# Bind DataSet and GridView (c#). What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, db2, database-connection

The button on my aspx page, on-click must fetch me the results from the **DB2 Database**. I'm using an ODBC Connection. On **clicking it just doesnt show any values**, neither any error message. **What is wrong with my code?**

```
using (OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(db2con))
{
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, db2con);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
try
{
odbcConnection.Open();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
Label1.Text = "fail";
}
}
```

---

Query= `select * from schema.student`

---

Connection String= `Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};database=demo;hostname=xx.xx.xx.xx;protocol=TCPIP;port=50000;uid=db2admin;pwd=xxxx;`

Comment: Do you have data in dataSet?

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with this.  Have you verified that your button is wired up?

Comment: @VladBezden no, i dont think so...

Comment: @BrianP yes, the code is inside the button click event

Comment: When you run your query directly via database do you get data back?

Comment: @VladBezden yup, it fetches the result

Comment: shouldn't you choose what datatable in the dataset to display?
I mean GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```